# Authentication issues with cloud scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

Can't figure out what could possible be wrong. I've deployed a service, set the trigger to require authentication.

Created a new service account for the cloud scheduler: `scheduler-invoker@<REDACTED>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Went to cloud run's permissions and added that account as cloud run invoker (although during creation I have already set up that role)

On cloud scheduler, I add this account as the service account, and the audience is set to theurl of the service.

But invocations are failing with a 403 error. Can't figure out this one, followed every step outlined at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler and I'm pretty sure I've done this in the past with no issues.

Any ideas?

I saw a few posts here on SO but even after reading them I'm still on the same spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the fact that I was on a project where cloud scheduler was activated before 2019. Adding `service-[project-number]@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com` seems to fix it

Comment: If this answered the question, consider accepting your own answer so other community members with similar issues can see and use this solution